# Http requests withCredentials what is this and why using it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I had a problem with CORS with node and angular and adding this option with true solved my problem.
But I don't find info about what it is and what it is doing.
Please can someone explain?

Comment: Can you not use withCredential and share a screenshot of your console CORS error?

Comment: Its not an error, it doesnt save me the session variables between pages.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`withCredentials()` makes your browser include cookies and authentication headers in your XHR request. If your service depends on any cookie (including session cookies), it will only work with this option set.

**Longer explanation:**

When you issue an Ajax request to a different origin server, the browser may send an OPTIONS pre-flight request to the server to discover the CORS policy of the endpoint (for non-GET requests).

Since the request may have been triggered by a malicious script, to avoid automatically leaking authentication information to the remote server, the browser applies the following rules :

For GET requests, include cookie and authentication information in the server request :

- if XHR client is invoked with the `withCredentials` option is set to true
- and if the server reply does not include the CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, discard response before returning the object to Javascript

For non GET requests, include cookie and authentication information only:

- if `withCredentials` is set to true on the XHR object
- and the server has included the CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` in the pre-flight OPTIONS

Comment: @rluta - my angular application is not returning authentication cookie even though I have set `withCredentials` to `true`. Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076352/angular-is-not-sending-the-cookie-received-in-set-cookie

Comment: but any malicious script can also set the withCredentials option to be true, seems it does not that important...

Comment: My angular application is returning a cookie with different name/value : [how-to-decode-credentials-sent-using-withcredentials-true-from-angular-cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965054/how-to-decode-credentials-sent-using-withcredentials-true-from-angular-cookie) can someone check the possibles reasons ?

Comment: How about the peculiar case : 
Api is the same server for dev/QA environment but different for uat/production[CORS] environment.

Comment: So this basically applies *only* when you use sessionid. But if you dont, such as if you use jwt instead, withcredentials are useless

Answer (score 5):

Short answer from [Axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios)
`withCredentials` indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials

> Credentials are cookies, authorization headers or TLS client certificates [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)

Default value of `withCredentials` is `false`

Comment: So this basically applies only when you use sessionid. But if you dont, such as if you use jwt instead, withcredentials are useless