# How to get the headers from HTTP response when using http.post

Tags: angular5

I am using `HttpClient` in Angular. The documentation says:

> All HttpClient methods return an RxJS Observable of something...HttpClient.get returns the body of the response as an untyped JSON object by default

Does this mean that in the following code, `res` is the HTTP message body (excluding the headers)?

```js
this.http.post('http://localhost:8083', body, options)
    .map((res) => { res.json(); console.log('got response'); })
```

How could I get the HTTP headers if I want to see that a certain header is present in the server's response?

Comment: Thanks @Kalanamith. I am checking this. Could you please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076352/angular-is-not-sending-the-cookie-received-in-set-cookie-even-if-withcredentials I am stuck at this for sometime now and have no clue how to solve this

Comment: seems you are not setting cookies

Comment: sorry, I dont follow. Could you please elaborate. I assume that when the server sends `Set-Cookie`, the client would automatically send the cookies in subsequent requests. Isn't it? How do I explicitly set the cookie in Angular? Also, could we please take this conversation to the question page. Others might find your answer helpful

Comment: @Kalanamith - any idea what I might be doing wrong in the problem in which Angular is not returning Cookie? Could you please comment on that question thread.

Comment: I cannot give a comment without seeing your whole working code

Comment: I understand. The issue is resolved now.