# Why cookie does not store in browser in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: ajax, http, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using cookie authentication in ASP.NET Core Web API. When I am requesting for login from Postman, cookie is shown in Postman.

But when I am requesting it from ajax, the cookie does not get stored in the browser.

Here is my Ajax request - am I missing anything in Ajax?

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'http://localhost:61610/api/auth/login',
    method: 'POST',
    xhrFields: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(para),
    dataType: 'application/json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(result);
        alert(status);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this

```
 xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need do some change in your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:61610/api/auth/login',
    method: 'POST',
    xhrFields: {              
        withCredentials: true                 
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(a),
    dataType: 'application/json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(result);
        alert(status);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

**then you can send ajax with cookie**

[image]

Here is a link with a more detailed explanation：

[Http requests withCredentials what is this and why using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406994/http-requests-withcredentials-what-is-this-and-why-using-it)